# Word for "code literacy"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Now I'm not certain there is an answer to this, but I was trying to think of a more elegant way of talking about the ability to understand code and programming concepts. It's a relativity new idea, so I'm open to newly coined phrases, ideas etc.

Example: "Our priority is that our students become literate, numerate and [code literate]"

Comment: Google Books claims about 90,900 results for [computer literate](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22computer+literate%22), but only 169 for [code literate](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22code+literate%22). I don't think there's any commonly-used single word equivalent.

Comment: I thought so too. I didn't know the difference between the two was so vast! I use them interchangeably.

Comment: It could work, but programming to computer literacy is as writing to literacy, no? The former assumes the latter, but is distinct

Comment: The boundary between *writing code* (creating "new" apps) and *parameterizing* (configuring existing "apps") gets increasingly fuzzy these days. Plus there's the difference between being able to read code / parameter script well enough to understand how it works, and actually *writing* it. Just as plenty of literary critics couldn't write a decent novel or poem, even though they can explain someone else's work in great detail.

Comment: It's not a new concept -- the industry has been searching for better terms for this for decades.

Comment: @hotlicks relative to the formation of language and the terms literacy and numeracy.

Comment: I think what you're looking for a word for doesn't really exist as a single, well-understood competency; certainly not in a way that is parallel to literacy and numeracy. The trend that @FumbleFingers  identifies is also happening in parallel to devices becoming *less* configurable and more generally amenable to being directly interacted with (by touch, gesture, voice, etc).

Comment: So what's wrong with "computer literacy"?  (There's a reason they're called "code monkeys".)

Comment: @Mark: There are often different ways you can instruct / control an intelligent device (including even slight variations in how you use swiping, say words for voice i/p, historically "likely" contextual interpretation, etc.). In many ways it's getting harder to distinguish *the machine learning from **you*** from ***you** "teaching" the machine how it should respond*.

Comment: @HotLicks "Computer literacy" usually is understood to mean being comfortable with *operating* a computer—being familiar with concepts like files, directories, and applications. That doesn't require any familiarity with programming languages, which is what the questioner is looking for.

Comment: What word comes to mind for *mathematical proof literacy*?

Comment: And *develop a programming mentality*

Comment: @MarkCogan - Any term you choose will be vague and will be quickly corrupted.  There is a big difference, eg, between "coding" and "programming".

Comment: What about "fluent?"

Comment: The term *code* might not fit with *literate* and *numerate*. If the sentence describes a computer-oriented class or program, *code* makes sense but *literate* and *numerate* are out of place; for a more-general education program, *code* is probably both too ambiguous and, ironically, too specific to be in the same company as *literate* and *numerate*.

Comment: @VedaadShakib I like it, especially considering how we use programming "languages". Add it as an answer and I'll give it an upvote for certain. At the end of the week I'll accept the most upvoted answer.

Answer (score 4):

***[Savvy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/savvy)*** could possibly fit your context well.

> (adj.) knowledgeable or proficient; often used in combination: *tech-savvy, media-savvy*

[The Free Dictionary]

**Usage:**

> "Our priority is that our students become literate, numerate and ***code-savvy***"

Comment: I also like proficient, though perhaps that suggests a certain ability beyond that of merely understanding code. Code sufficient perhaps?

Comment: @Ogaday - Sounds fine. Interestingly, I got a weird Ngram plot for ["code sufficient"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=code+sufficient&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccode%20sufficient%3B%2Cc0) and no plots for ["code-savvy"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=code+savvy&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) (wow!). Whatever works for you...

Answer (score 2):

**Fluent** is a decent choice, since programming languages fit into the category of languages in general.

> able to speak a language easily and very well

Comment: Except that fluency is usually associated with a specific language, vs with the ability to reason with the higher concepts involved.

Comment: @HotLicks Bro, nothing's gonna match what he wants perfectly in one word. I've personally heard fluent being used in this context in many situations.